# Adding 1000 routes to MVC5 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

To avoid showing the ID of a webpage in the URL I'm thinking of adding routes which can help figure out the ID based on the URL text.

In other words,

**Do Not Want**: `/pages/3232/some-webpage`

**Prefer**: `/pages/some-webpage` (where `some-webpage` will mean ID=3232)

**Will it be an overkill** if I add like 1000 of these routes to our MVC5 app running on a 8GB RAM Intel Xeon 2.2GHz Dual Core?

Any drawbacks of this approach?

Comment: Do you mean you are also going to create 1000 action methods - e.g. `public ActionResult some-webpage()` in `pagesController`? Why are you not just creating one action method that accepts a parameter for `some-webpage`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke No. I was thinking along the lines of one action that satisfies these 1000 routes. The action can extract the route value for `pageID` and fetch the right page. Anyway let us see what the answer below is suggesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you really want to do :-) is to use a "fallback route" which caches all the requests not handled by any other route and a controller action which then extracts the slug ("some-webpage") from the url, doing a lookup in your data store for the correct resource.

Comment: I'd also mention this should require a custom extension methods for `UrlHelper` and `Html.ActionLink()` to backwards create urls.

Comment: @ErikPhilips - If you inherit RouteBase, the backward lookups can be done in the `GetVirtualPath` method. There is no need to create custom ActionLink overloads for this.

Comment: @asp_net now the question arises for SQL Server db - will indexing a `nvarchar(128)` which is page url column cause any performance issue for a 1000 row table? It doesn't sound like but just checking

Comment: @greatbear302 Depends like always on the underlying performance of your server, but 1.000 records should never be an issue. And at the end of the day you can still cache it in memory (in its simplest way in a static dictionary for example).